# How can I calculate the total price of all items in my cart in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
foreach ($_SESSION as $products) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 3) {
            echo '<td class="product_total">$' . intval($value) . '</td>';
        } elseif ($key == 2) {
            echo '<td class="product_quantity">' . $value . '</td>';
            $q = $value;
        } elseif ($key == 1) {
            echo "<td class='product-price' > $" . $value . "</td>";
            $p = $value;
        } elseif ($key == 0) {
            echo "<td class='product_name'> " . $value . "</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't assume that the only thing in `$_SESSION` is products. You should probably just have a single session variable to hold the cart.

Comment: Don't use a loop with `if` statements to access specific elements. Just use `$products[3]` to get the price, `$products[2]` to get the quantity, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the product's total price to an accumulator variable.

```
<?php
$total = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION as $products) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='product_name'> " . $products[0] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='product-price' > $" . $products[1] . "</td>";
    echo '<td class="product_quantity">' . $products[2] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="product_total">$' . intval($products[3]) . '</td>';
    $total += intval($products[3]);
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<td>Total</td><td colspan='2'></td><td>$" . $total . "</td>";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Bamar for solving my issue.